# The existence of a solution to an arithmetic system in Serre's Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

I have a question about a proof in Serre's A course in arithmetic (proposition 5, page 63-64). Specifically, I wonder how to prove that there exists an integer $x$ such that

> $\left(\dfrac{x}{l_1}\right)=-1, x\equiv 1\pmod{4l_2\cdots l_k}$, where $l_1,\dots,l_k$ are primes distinct from $2$ (see below at the end of the picture).

It seems to Serre that the existence of such $x$ is immediate, but I don't know why. Also please refrain from using Dirichlet's theorem about the existence of infinitely many primes equal to a given integer mod m, which is to be prove in this chapter of Serre.
[image]

Comment: Just use the Chinese remainder theorem. Pick a non residue $a\pmod {l_1}$ and then use the CRT to produce a class $\equiv 1 \pmod {4l_2\cdots l_k}$ and $\equiv a \pmod {l_1}$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! But why does there always exist a non-residue $a \pmod{l_1}$? At least this is not obvious from the definition of Legendre symbol

Comment: Sure it is.  The quadratic residues are the squares and there are $\frac {l_1-1}2$ non zero squares $\pmod {l_1}$ (since $\pm n$ have the same square).